# django media not found (uploaded in admin page)

Tags: python, django

I'v set an Imagefield for one of my Models in this way:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default='/defaultavatar.jpg')
```

and this is my setting for media root and url:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'site_media/media/')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'site_media/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

when I create a profile I can access `defalutavatar.jpg` but when I upload another image via admin page and try to open image it says `404 Not Found` (although image is created in MEDIA_ROOT)

DEBUG is false (in case you want to suggest `urlpattern += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`)

Comment: when DEBUG is false,django no longer handle media file and static file,you need to server media file and static file by apache or something else

Comment: @Ykh can you give me a hint. i'm using a shared host and completely new to server stuffs.

Comment: you want put your project in production now?

Comment: @Ykh it is in production right now actually. everything is fine but this.

Comment: nginx or apache or supervisor?

Comment: @Ykh Apache/2.4.10

Comment: i will give a demo conf

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin ykh@dreamgo.tech
    ServerName 192.168.1.102

    DocumentRoot /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site

    Alias /static /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/static
    <Directory /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/media
    <Directory /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/dreamgo_official_site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess 192.168.1.102 python-path=/home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site python-home=/home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/environment
    WSGIProcessGroup 192.168.1.102
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dreamgo/dreamgo_official_site/dreamgo_official_site/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```